# Error with encoding apostrophe to and from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, apostrophe

I have an html string that is dynamically created server side.

```
strHTML = "<td><a href""google.com"" onclick=""SaveToDatabase('" + arrString(0) + "','" + arrString(1) + "')""
```

The value of arrString(1) is **javascript:OpenDoc('ProductManual.pdf','vbShowDoc')**

**Error Message: Expected ')'**

How can I encode this value to save in the database, and decode it when retreving it from the database ?

Comment: How are you trying to save to your db?  Could we see the code you are using when saving to the DB? You should be using parametrization when sending updates to the DB.

Comment: @John, the query to save is pretty simple ExecuteNonQuery. What do you mean by parameterization?

Comment: When Saving to the database you should not create your query statment like this.  `query = "Update TableA set Column1 = '" & someStringVar & "' where PrimaryKey = ' & someStringVar2 & "'"`.  Instead you should use parametrized queries as show in this link http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: is your error message from the browser of the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**simple**

you should replace `'` to  `\'`

(C#)

```
arrString(0)=arrString(0).replace("'",@"\'")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are 
SaveToDatabase('whatever','javascript:OpenDoc('ProductManual.pdf','vbShowDoc')')""

note the problem with your quotes here. you have an opening quote at 'javascript    but your closing quote it taken to be after OpenDoc('   thats not your closing quote, hence use \'
You need to encode your quote with \'

Also see:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1047952.aspx

Edit:
I see Mid787 beat me to it, but I wanted to provide some additional info

Comment: The additional info is appreciated, however, I am still getting the same error msg:  Expected ')' Line: 1       The line 1 part makes no sense when I use IE scriptDebugger

Comment: using your suggestion, this is the line that is possibly causing the error   javascript:ProcessElements('3','Product Manual~Javascript:OpenDoc(''g'',''NEW'');','','');

Answer (score 1):

Any time you read input from the user or any outside source, you should ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS escape it before attempting to build a SQL command from it.

One way to do this is to use prepared statements or stored procedures and use the built-in function calls to set variables. Then the function will take care of any escaping.

If you want or need to hand-build the SQL, write a function to escape it. For most SQL engines, it is sufficient to look for any embedded single quotes and double them, that is, turn

Pat O'Hara said 'Hello'

into

Pat O''Hara said ''Hello''

Some SQL engines have other characters that require escaping, like in Postgres you should also double back-slashes.

It's easy enough to write a function to do this, and then ALWAYS use it.

I've had many conversations with programmers where they say they didn't bother in this case because they didn't think it was likely that anyone would ever enter a quote into this particular field. But usually the reason we're having the conversation is because some one did. Don't analyze it! Just do it! It's like wearing a seat belt. You could sit there and calculate the odds that you'll get in an accident on this particular trip, but why? The wise driver makes it a mindless, automatic act to just always put on his seatbelt, even if all he's doing is moving the car from the driveway to the street. The wise database programmer always escapes input strings, because you never know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass in a string like

```
INSERT dbo.table(foo) VALUES('foo'bar');
```

You need to double up the apostrophes:

```
INSERT dbo.table(foo) VALUES('foo''bar');
```

But @John Hartsock is absolutely right: you shouldn't be sending ad hoc concatenated strings to SQL Server. If you use parameters you can avoid this issue altogether.